# Trying to parse data from a table

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the link I am trying to get the table from.

https://secure.conservation.ca.gov/WellSearch/Details?api=08322855

Whatever I have done, cannot get the td values.

Tried beautifulsoup, pandas. No luck...

Here is a version of several attempts... results are the same. ]

```
    page = requests.get('https://secure.conservation.ca.gov/WellSearch/Details?api='+str(line[1])).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

[production table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUqNv.png)

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Hello I am trying to get td values from the production table. please see the link and table called production data... Thanks much!

Comment: Charles gave the solution to this problem. Thank you Charles.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the productionTable with BeautifulSoup because this table is generated with javascript.
As you can see, the following code shows that the productionTable is empty :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://secure.conservation.ca.gov/WellSearch/Details?api=08322855'.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", {"id": "productionTable"})

table
```

Output with empty tbody :

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="display table table-responsive table-striped" id="productionTable" role="grid" style="font-size:12px; width:100%; text-align: center;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Oil(bbl)</th>
<th>Water(bbl)</th>
<th>Gas(Mcf)</th>
<th>Days Producing</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Gravity of Oil">Gravity</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Casing Pressure">Csg</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tubing Pressure">Tbg</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="British thermal unit">BTU</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Method of Operation">MO</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Water Disposition">Disp</th>
<th>PWT Status</th>
<th>Well Type</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reported Well Status">Status</th>
<th>Pool Code</th>
<th>Sum</th>
<th>Row</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Oil(bbl)</th>
<th>Water(bbl)</th>
<th>Gas(Mcf)</th>
<th>Days Producing</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Gravity of Oil">Gravity</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Casing Pressure">Csg</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tubing Pressure">Tbg</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="British thermal unit">BTU</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Method of Operation">MO</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Water Disposition">Disp</th>
<th>PWT Status</th>
<th>Well Type</th>
<th data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reported Well Status">Status</th>
<th>Pool Code</th>
<th>Sum</th>
<th>Row</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The good news is you can run a script that download the excel file :
After having installed a webdriver https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8
and having done pip install selenium :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print('driver is ok !\n\n')

driver.get('https://secure.conservation.ca.gov/WellSearch/Details?api=08322855')
button = driver.find_element_by_id('ButtonExportProdToExcel')
button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. It does not look like it pulls the table values... please see the production data table and numbers in the link.

Comment: I updated my answer ;)

Comment: if you don't want Chrome to display, you can follow this tuto https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python

Comment: Thanks so much Charles!! I will give it a try and let you know. I really appreciate your contribution!